# Gmail API sending limits and cost

Tags: email, smtp, gmail-api

What are the sending limits of using the Gmail API?

This article says that mail.send takes 100 Quota Units of a 1,000,000,000 qu per day: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Elsewhere, individual users are limited to 500 out-of-domain emails per day. The test emails I've sent with the API appear to come from the account which authorized the App.: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Which is it for the Gmail API whose credentials use a single G Suite user's account - and does that affect the 500 external/2000 internal messages the account can send normally?

The use case is using a WordPress plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/) to use SMTP via the Gmail API instead of the local mailserver.

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run into several *different* limits.

First is the "quota units" you describe for general API usage.

But you're more likely to run into the "daily mail sending limits".  See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

> **The Gmail API enforces the standard daily mail sending limits** (these
>   limits differ for paying G Suite users vs free gmail.com users).
>
> These limits are per-user and are shared by all of the user's clients,
>   whether API clients, native/web clients or SMTP MSA. If these limits
>   are exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests "User-rate limit exceeded"
>   error mentioning "(Mail sending)" is returned with a time to retry.
>   Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of
>   errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted, so your
>   client may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.

(emphasis added)  And the referenced limits are documented in the link you cited:  https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852

The limits there are:  2,000 per day (or 500 for trial accounts), which applies to both internal and external recipients.